# Using NSNotificationCenter of iOS or similar event app events in Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, nsnotificationcenter

An alternative answer could be if there are any kind of hooks in Unity corresponding to  these events:

- UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
- UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

Can I use NSNotificationCenter of iOS in Unity? How? I googled for a while but found zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html

OnApplicationFocus

However, it does not work on iOS at least. Seems like it's a bug and will be fixed in Unity 4.6.1... I use 4.6 (4.6.0f3)

http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/monobehaviour-dot-onapplicationfocus-not-supported-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is to be notified when a few of the delegate methods are called.  To do that, you can edit the AppDelegate.m file and add a line of code that will pass messages back into your Unity game.  I can give you a general how-to here.

First create a GameObject in your root scene and attach a script with a method you want to call, and a call to `DontDestroyOnLoad()`.  Also give it a unique name in the hierarchy which you will need later, like **AppDelegateProxy**.

```
void Start() {
    DontDestroyOnLoad();
}

public void ApplicationWillResignActive(string message) {
    // Do whatever you want here, e.g. fire an event
}
```

Next, in your app's AppDelegate.m file, edit the relevant method you want to pass along to Unity:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Notify your game object that this event occurred
    UnitySendMessage("AppDelegateProxy", "ApplicationWillResignActive", "whatever you want here");
}
```

There are other ways to do what you want, but this is a general method that will let you respond to anything in your iOS app that you want.  You can also use this generally to pass notifications into the app as well.  Just set up a listener in your AppDelegate and pass notifications to a method in your persistent GameObject.